# In kendo Angular UI close DropdownButton option when click on other dropdown

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

**Here is kendo AngularUI dropdownButton all dropdown comes dynamatically so there is not fixed number of kendo-dropdownbutton**

```
`<div (click)="onDropdownClick($event)">
        <kendo-dropdownbutton [data]="toolbarData">User Settings<img src="../assets/images/arrow.svg" />
        </kendo-dropdownbutton>
        <kendo-dropdownbutton [data]="toolbarData">User Settings<img src="../assets/images/arrow.svg" />
        </kendo-dropdownbutton>
        <kendo-dropdownbutton [data]="toolbarData">User Settings<img src="../assets/images/arrow.svg" />
        </kendo-dropdownbutton>
      </div>`
```

**here  kendo-dropdownbutton option **

```
`public toolbarData = [
    {
      text: "Bold",
      iconClass: "fas fa-bold",
    },
    {
      text: "Italic",
      iconClass: "fas fa-italic",
    },
    {
      text: "Strike",
      iconClass: "fas fa-strikethrough",
    },
    {
      text: "GIF",
      iconClass: "fas fa-image",
    },
  ];`
```

**without removing the stopPropagation code provide solution of when i click on other dropdown then alreday opened dropdown should close.**

```
`onDropdownClick(event: Event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }`
```

clicking on any dropdown will close the currently open one dropdown option. without removing  event.stopPropagation(); this.

Comment: Are you doing something custom to open the dropdowns manually? In the [demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/buttons/dropdownbutton/) in the docs, the buttons close automatically when another button is clicked. You can use that same demo to reproduce your issue in a stackblitz.